# Error with Heroku - Error encoding: latin-1 [HEROKU]

Tags: python, heroku, encoding

My application runs perfectly in "local" but when I run on Heroku it falls into exception, this is due to encoding, my application is using "latin-1", but on the server is pulling UTF-8, as a way to change in python?

Python:

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding( "latin-1" )
```

Exception:

```
except Exception:

        data.append({'return': {
            'payment': payment,
            'access_token': access_token,
            'url': url,
            'exception': 'Erro na validacao!'
        }})
        return jsonify(data)
```

HEROKU:

```
irb(main):001:0> "a".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Localhost:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdIGa.png)

Heroku:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGSJy.png)

Comment: Where exactly is the data being `encoded/decoded` ? Could you show us the code ?

Comment: As @hansolo said, we need far more information. Also, please include code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. Please see: [ask], [mcve].